# Uploading WordPress media files using XML-RPC

Tags: wordpress, jsp

> **This is my code.**

```
    public void fileUpload() throws Exception {
         byte fileByte[] =org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path+realName));
                String wpUpFile=fileToString(new File(path+realName));
                XmlRpcClient blog  = new XmlRpcClient();
                XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
                Hashtable<String, String> post = new Hashtable<>();
                Vector<Serializable> params = new Vector<Serializable>();
                config.setServerURL(url);
                config.setBasicUserName(user);
                config.setBasicPassword(pw);
                params.addElement(id);
                params.addElement(user);
                params.addElement(pw);
                post.put("name", realName);
                post.put("type", "image/jpeg");
                post.put("bits", wpUpFile);
                post.put("overwrite", "false");
                params.addElement(post);
                params.addElement(true);
                Object blogPostID = blog.execute(config, "wp.uploadFile", params);
    }
```

> **file base64 change code**

```
 public String fileToString(File file) throws IOException {
                String fileString = new String();
                FileInputStream inputStream =  null;
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int len = 0;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                             byteOutStream.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    byte[] fileArray = byteOutStream.toByteArray();
                    fileString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(fileArray));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    inputStream.close();
                    byteOutStream.close();
                }
               return fileString;
    }
```

> **result**

[image]

> The image file was not displayed properly. What is the problem?
> I dont know why this errors happend. Please let me know. Please help me.

Comment: use try-catch and inspect the exception in debug mode, the exception might be different there.

Comment: What is `fileToString`? AFAIK you have to base64 encode binary data when using xml-rpc.

Comment: fileToString is return base64 encode in to String.

Comment: You don't show us the code of this method, but you should know that `String base64Image=new String(fileByte,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` does **not** do any base 64 encoding